# What do these posts mean?

Tags: united-nations, executive

In the organisation of the UN, what are the roles of these posts:

1. Secretary General of the UN.
2. Director General.
3. General Counsel and Head of Global Public Policy
4. First Vice President (The post that Ligia Noronhu holds).

Comment: Are you asking about roles at the UN ?

Comment: @JamesK Yes. I am.

Comment: Have you tried reading https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations ? It has a list with links to detailed answers.

Comment: @PaulJohnson hat is role of director here. It is nowhere written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UN has bodies such as the Security Council that are composed of representatives of the various nations.  And a body, called the "Secretariat" that organises and runs the UN. THe members of the secretariat are employed by the UN and the over vision and goal of the UN is to promote a peaceful and sustainable world.

The [Secretary-General](https://www.un.org/sg/en) is the head of the Secretariat.  He or she is the chief administrator of the UN and has an unofficial role in acting as a go-between between the countries.

Below the Secretary-General there are a [team](https://www.un.org/sg/en/content/senior-management-group) of Under-Secretaries-General, each of whom heads a department, although the exact titles vary.

The United Nations has three major regional offices (in Geneva, Nairobi, and Vienna) Each is headed by a [Director-General](https://www.un.org/sg/en/content/profiles/tatiana-valovaya), who ranks as an Under-Secretary.  Their role is the run the regional office.

A General-Councel is lead lawyer. The exact job title you refer to does not seem to exist but perhaps you are referring to the [Under-Secretary-General for Legal Affairs and UN Legal Counsel](https://www.un.org/sg/en/content/profiles/miguel-de-serpa-soares)

All the above roles are at the senior management group level.

But I think by "Global Public Policy" you are referring to the [UN Global Compact](https://www.unglobalcompact.org/) Which is a body that promotes the goals of the UN through Business (Public policy is about how Government interact with Business.) The Head of the UN Global compact is not a Senior management group role

Finally [Ligia Noronha](https://www.unep.org/people/ligia-noronha) is the Director of the UN Environmental Program in New York.  The Envionmental Program is based in Nairobi, and its head (Inger Andersen) is based there in Kenya.  But the UNEP has an office at the UN headquarters in New York.  Ms Noronha is the director of that office.  Hers is not a senior management group role.

Comment: Excellent explanation but why first vice president? I am unable to follow this.

Comment: I don't know.  You mentioned "first vice president" not me.  Her job title isn't "First vice president"

Comment: What is the exact meaning of director general apart from United nations?

Comment: Please use a dictionary https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/director_general

Comment: What is meant by executive officer. How is it different from that of an administrative officer?

Comment: Please use a dictionary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124587/discussion-between-rajorshi-koyal-and-james-k).

Comment: An executive officer is generally a person responsible for running an organization, although the exact nature of the role varies depending on the organization.
An Administrative Officer, or Admin Officer, is responsible for providing administrative support to an organization. Their duties include organizing company records, overseeing department budgets and maintaining inventory of office supplies.

Comment: both of them seem so similar